# Firebase query not giving result set

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Firebase data organized in the below format. When I'm trying to fetch data using the below code, it just never enters `onDataChange`, even though I have data in Firebase at that path.

Please ignore the list part, in the log I am able to see right path of Firebase, i.e.:

> conversation/8masp4NLZrYL4HpziIU7uUZjRd73/8masp4NLZrYL4HpziIU7uUZjRd73

[image: Snapshot of firebase]

```
DatabaseReference databaseReferenceAdapter = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference conversation2Ref  = databaseReferenceAdapter.child("conversation").child(currentUser).child(userListRef.get(position));

Log.d(TAG,"Data binding++++" + conversation2Ref.getRef().toString());

conversation2Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Data changed");
        Conversation conversationInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversation.class);
        mConversationList.add(position,conversationInfo);
        Log.d(TAG,"Data changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        Log.d(TAG,"Data error");
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is either with currentUser or your userListRef or position or your conversation class. Please provide the code where you are adding values in UserListRef and your Conversation class too. And where are you keeping the currentUser or position values. Provide the minimum necessary code so that otherr can help you better. Also provide the logcat crash report too.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those values, instead of using `Conversation.cass`, you can use the `String.class` like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("conversation").child("8masp4NLZrYL4HpziIU7uUZjRd73").child("8masp4NLZrYL4HpziIU7uUZjRd73");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);
        long notificationCount = dataSnapshot.child("notificationCount").getValue(Long.class);
        long profileId = dataSnapshot.child("profileId").getValue(String.class);
        String profileName = dataSnapshot.child("profileName").getValue(String.class);
        long time = dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue(String.class);
        String type = dataSnapshot.child("type").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
child(userListRef.get(position));
```

The above is wrong, according to the database you have random `push()` key under the `userid`. So, you have to retrieve the push key and add it to the child.

to retrieve the key:

```
String key=conversation2Ref.push().getKey()
```

then in query do:

```
child(key)
```